# Вращение изображения при скроллинге страницы JS+CSS3

Tags: css3, jquery, html5, css, javascript

Добрый день! Прошу помощи у общества, ибо сам застрял.
**Задача:**
Часовое колесо должно вращаться при скроллинге страницы вверх-вниз. Нигде не могу найти информацию или туториал по данному вопросу...
Плиз хелп!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/ тут я реализовал и вращение и смещение от скроллинга

Comment: @eicto, психоделика.

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять позицию скролла: `var x = $(document).scrollTop()` и использовать плагин [jqueryrotate.js](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_5) в зависимости от значения `x`.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но можно немного по-подробнее? Дело в том, что я не сильно разбираюсь в JS, а делать надо. До сих пор обходился банальными копи-пастами и готовыми плагинами, а тут не свезло...  
Спасибо заранее!